# Hiding a Row From a ResultSet

Tags: java, sql

I have a result set that sometimes has to take in rows that are blank.

It looks like there is function for ResultSet that allows you to delete the row entirely, called `resultSet.deleteRow()`. However, it looks like this also deletes the row from the database it's linked to.

How can I hide the row only from the resultSet (and not delete it from the database) when every column in the row is "null"?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not search for the data in that row and if you find it, just skip over it?

Comment: Why do you need to need to delete row? Why not simply skip that row based on whatever condition you want.

Comment: I've tried making it appear blank, but when I do this, on the web-page, you can actually see the blank rows appear as empty lines. So I thought deleting it from the resultSet would be best. Want to give me an example of how to skip it from being added to the resultSet to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove rows or update a ResultSet. You have to use a CachedRowSet.
If you want you can loop through the result set and add the elements in a list or map and then just remove the non-required elements from that data structure. Better option is to modify your sql and get only the data you want in the result set.

Comment: Right, I tried to block the results I don't need from coming back, but instead of not showing the row entirely, it still returns the row, with every column just being blank.